Simplifying this data structure: Rc<RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>
I have some data Vec<T> that is stored -- wrapped in some data structure -- in a HashMap.
From this HashMap, I want to retrieve two types of copies of this Vec<T>:

"real" (but lazy) copies, which when modified will not affect the original Vec<T> and will also not be affected when the original Vec<T> is modified.
mutable views, which will allow to mutate the original Vec<T> stored in the HashMap but which will not modify all the "real" copies. (There will be at most exactly one such mutable view, but it is necessary to be able to create more real copies in the presence of such a mutable view). I don't have to worry what happens when the original Vec<T> is modified when I have such a mutable view, as this cannot happen. Also, there will only be one such mutable view.

The data structure I came up with is a Rc<RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>.
To create real copies, I can clone the inner Rc and wrap it into a new outer Rc<RefCell<...>>, giving it its own RefCell. To create the mutable copies, I can just clone the outer Rc, which will share RefCells.
Modifying the content of the Vec<T> can then always be achieved by using RefCell::replace_with().
I think this achieves what I want, but what I don't like about this solution is that it is a rather complex data structure and I was wondering whether this can also be achieved using a simpler solution?
Why I cannot use Rc<Vec<T>> (I think):
Just relying on an Rc<Vec<T>> almost does what I want, and I would love to just use this data structure for simplicity. The problem is, however, that when I create a &mut T using make_mut(), no other real copies can be created from the Rc<Vec<T>>.
Edit:
I think I did not specify what I want here explicitly enough, so I am now trying to give more information

I am not (yet) in a multi-threaded scenario, so I don't need to worry about this for now.
I want the "real" copies do be done lazily, i.e. only once they are modified, they will create a copy of the data. But their data should not be modified when a mutable view is modified. E.g. if x is the original vector, x1 and x2 real copies and x3 a mutable view, they should in the beginning all have the same Vec<T>. When I write into x3, this should then only modify the content of x and x3, but not x1 and x2, which should still contain the same Vec<T>.
There will only be one mutable view at a time.
Changing the contents of such a variable will only ever be done via mutable views.

Why I can't use Rc<Vec<T>>:
The problem with this data structure is that I want to get mutable access to the data stored in the Rc when there are 2 references, one in the HashMap and one retrieved from the hashmap, namely the object that I want to mutate.
let map = HashMap::new();
map.insert("x".to_string(), Rc::new(vec![1])), 
let x1 = Rc::clone(map.get("x").unwrap());
// I want to be able to write to x1 and simultatenously modify the content of x in the HashMap

Because these two references will always exist, this means that the Rc::make_mut() will unfortunately not directly solve my problem, as I want mutable access when the Rc count is 2 and not 1.
My current solution:
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    map.insert("x".to_string(), Rc::new(RefCell::new(Rc::new(vec![1]))));

    // create two "real", but lazy clones
    let x1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Rc::clone(&map["x"].borrow())));
    let x2 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Rc::clone(&map["x"].borrow())));

    // create a mutable clone and modify it, directly changing the x in the HashMap
    let x3 = Rc::clone(&map["x"]);
    {
        let x = (&mut *x3.borrow_mut());
        let x = Rc::make_mut(x);
        x.push(2);
    }
    println!("{:?}", x1.borrow());
    println!("{:?}", x2.borrow());
    println!("{:?}", x3.borrow());
    println!("{:?}", map["x"].borrow());

    return ()
}

Running this will output:
[1]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]


One thing that could be simplified is converting RefCell to Cell: Rc<Cell<Rc<Vec>>. A "real copy" could be extracted from a "mutable view" by using let real = unsafe {(&*mutable.as_ptr()).clone()}.

A Rc<Vec<_>> should be able to do what you want, can you come up with an example of what you can't do with it? (And that can't be resolved by just creating an additional clone of it)

I think, maybe I can just use Rc<Rc<Vec>

@trueequalsfalse I think I would like to avoid unsafe for the time being.

@cafce25 I updated the question as to why I think it does not work.

@Sebastian For your example you can just create an additional clone of the Rc, it's cheap anyways.

Do you think it solves my point 2. which I listed under "Edit" at the bottom?

Depends as to what you understand under "real copy" you've used the term in conflicting ways.

Yeah, I think I have chosen the name poorly. What I mean with real is that it behaves like a real copy, i.e. writing to it does not modify the variable from which it was created and writing to the variable from which it was created does not modify the real copy. But the scenario where both are not modified is optimized to avoid cloning, so in that sense it behaves like a "real copy" but is done lazily.

Then yes, that is solved by just having another copy, you simply only call make_mut at the moment you actually modify the data, not earlier. Still nothing you've described cannot be done with a Rc<Vec<_>>

Sounds like Copy-on-write?

Sorry for phrasing everything so poorly ...
The problem why I cannot use Rc<Vec<>> is that the reference count will always be 2 when I want to mutable the Vec<>, one in the HashMap where the objects are stored and one that was retrieved from the HashMap and to which I want to write.

Yes, I want copy on write with the restriction that I want  mutable access when the Rc count is 2 and not 1.

Yes, in this case the Rc count is 4, which means when I write to x3 I need to copy the vector, which will change the content of x and x3, but not of x1 and x2, which will still have the original vector. But if there was only x and x3, I want to avoid this copy.

That does not make sense, if you have 2 references you have to make a copy, else you're modifying a "true copy".

Yes, this is why Rc<Vec<_>> does not work, but it is the behavior I need.

Hence, the data structure that I suggested is a Rc<RefCell<Rc<Vec<_>>> and not a Rc<Vec<_>>

You should add working example code of what you are trying to accomplish using your working solution. Personally I think your original solution is good enough without unsafe, unless someone has already created a library that does exactly this.

I have updated the question to include my solution. Thanks for all your patience and help!

You can simplify your structure a bit by having a wrapper around RefCell<Rc> that only gives you a get_clone() and set() methods. This way, you don't litter your code with borrow()s and possible panics, and if performance ever become a problem, you can switch to UnsafeCell yet encapsulate the unsafe code very cleanly.

Still seems to be doable with Rc<Vec<_>> (or RefCell<Rc<Vec<_>>>)

no, then i can’t create other lazy copies (like x1, x2)  while the mutable reference exists

@cafce25 The Rc on the outer layer may be necessary if doing something sufficiently more complicated than the example. For example using async with tokio::spawn_local, where static lifetime on shared objects is necessary, something Rc provides.

thanks for the tip with the UnsafeCell @ChayimFriedman

@cafce25's suggestion of RefCell<Rc<Vec>>> seems to be exactly what you want.

@eggyal But then mutable views cannot exist, because they cannot change the original.

This can be made OK by having a dedicated struct that provides a mutable_view() and copy() methods. I don't believe you can go better.

@ChayimFriedman: My playground showed a view x mutating the map entry ?

@eggyal the problem with this suggestion is that while the mutable view exists, no other  lazy copies can be made

Ah yes, I hadn't noticed that requirement.  @ChayimFriedman: I don't see how the struct approach will help; mustn't whatever is returned by the mutable_view() method have a lifetime during which copy() is precluded from being called?  The requirements here feel fundamentally unsound: eg how do you avoid two simultaneous/conflicting mutable views?

mutable_view() just returns  Rc<RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>, so there are no lifetimes involved. The trick is that cloning the outer Rc gives the mutable view, because you have access to the same RefCell, whereas cloning the Inner Rc and wrapping it in a new Rc<RefCell<...>> gives a lazy copy, because then the mutable view or original are modified by replacing the refcell, they will not be affected.
So there is no need to handle lifetimes, as there are no references. Multiple mutable views would be tricky, but this cannot happen so I don't need to worry about it (for now).

Also two conflicting views can be easily avoided when all of this is wrapped in a struct. You can just consult the outer strong reference count and throw an error when it is already 2 and one wants to obtain another mutable view

@eggyal The struct is just a way to encapsulate this behavior, it does not change the fundamental approach.
